# Indent with parallel text Hebrew/Yiddish–Latin/German

Tags: indentation, hebrew, reledmac, dramatist

I'm having trouble with making a parallel version of a bilingual play. Each dramatis personae should have a own indent. Based on the `dramatis` package I use:

```
\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1} %for Hebrew page

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1} %for German page

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}
```

But the indent only appears with the German page. Any ideas how I can get this work for the Hebrew page too?

Example:

```
    % arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:16cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  } 


\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}


\setmainlanguage{german} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}

\begin{document}


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} \begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{First.}
{גם אַתה}.
  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!}}
 \pend


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{Second.}
 מייא איהר לייט, מער זעללט נאך אַביסכה וואַרטע מיט דעם עססע איך ווילל ערשט
 דען שופט רופע לאָססע, דער זאָלל
אַהך מיט עססע. האַלט אַביסכה אין! שמואל, רוהף אמויהל דען.
}}\pend

     \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart \speakerd{First.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. \pend 

\pstart \speakerd{Second.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed \pend
\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: In theory it should work with a negative `\hangindent`, but something about `\pstart` stuffs up `\hangindent` and `\parshape`. I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to get it working with xelatex and bidi, but with lualatex and babel it seems to work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:16cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  }

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel} 
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}

\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{\textdir TLT #1} \einzugjid}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}


\begin{document}


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} \selectlanguage{hebrew}
\beginnumbering

\pstart \speaker{First.}
{גם אַתה}.
  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!
 \pend


\pstart \speaker{Second.}
 מייא איהר לייט, מער זעללט נאך אַביסכה וואַרטע מיט דעם עססע איך ווילל ערשט
 דען שופט רופע לאָססע, דער זאָלל
אַהך מיט עססע. האַלט אַביסכה אין! שמואל, רוהף אמויהל דען.
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{english}
\beginnumbering

\pstart \speakerd{First.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Second.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed \pend
\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was *sure* I tried this! Oh well. It works now like this for me too.

Comment: Unfortunately it works only limited with me. Arara and the footnotes cause problems. Isn't it possible using Arara?

Comment: Why should there be a problem with arara?

Comment: No, it's not arara – its something with the bidi-package: I get the error-message `XeTeX is required to compile this document. https://github.com/bidi-tex/bidi/issues` maybe something with the other packages I am using.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I feel bad about just asking, but would you check my final header what's wrong with it using lualatex?

Comment: You can't use the bidi package with lualatex, you have to switch to babel and its bidi options.

Comment: But you probably added more stuff. My example compiles as it is without errors.

Comment: Then what is the babel command for bidis `\autofootnoterule`?

Comment: Yes, my header is "a mess" – and I think there is a problem with glossaries and lualatex?

Comment: The comments are not the right place to debug a document. If you have a new problem, ask a new question with a proper minimal example. Be aware that while imho the bidi-model of luatex is superior to that of xetex, the bidi support in babel is much newer than the bidi package and so can miss things.

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך if you choose to switch away from `bidi`+`xelatex` to `babel`+`lualatex`, then I suggest you start all your document set up from scratch. The two ways of doing things are very different and if you start with what you have now I think you will get all kinds of problems resulting from leftovers of `bidi`. But I agree with Ulrike, `babel`'s BiDi model is developing rapidly and I would choose to use it instead of the `bidi` package now.

Comment: Can't there be another option using XeLaTeX? The document simply doesn't compile with LuaLaTeX

Comment: Note with `babel`, bidi layout elements (lists, footnotes...) must be activated explicitly. See the manual, sec. 1.21, as well as the samples on https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/tree/master/required/babel/samples .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer don't you see any solution for this using XeLaTeX? I am really struggling with this. I am just aboit sending the manuscript to the publisher, but there is this single thing with the indent that causes big problems with  the XeLaTeX-working document when I change it to LuLaTeX, that I can't solve (e.g. with special glossarie-code you once wrote me, or special footnotes). I am really like lost here…

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about bidi anyway, and with bidi with xelatex even less. And you have the additional complication of reledmac.

Comment: is there a way to set the indent manually?