# Paralleltext Hebrew/Latin-indent

Tags: hebrew, parallel, dramatist, screenplay

I've posted this question before; but no one has reacted, so I try it once more.

I'm having trouble with making a parallel version of a bilingual play. Each dramatis personae should have a own indent. Based on the dramatis-package I use:

```
\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1} %for Hebrew page

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1} %for German page

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}
```

But the indent only appears with the German page. Any ideas how I can get this work for the Hebrew page too?

Example:

```
    % arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:16cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  } 


\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}


\setmainlanguage{german} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}

\begin{document}


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} \begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{First.}
{גם אַתה}.
  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע! אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!  אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!}}
 \pend


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{Second.}
 מייא איהר לייט, מער זעללט נאך אַביסכה וואַרטע מיט דעם עססע איך ווילל ערשט
 דען שופט רופע לאָססע, דער זאָלל
אַהך מיט עססע. האַלט אַביסכה אין! שמואל, רוהף אמויהל דען.
}}\pend

     \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart \speakerd{First.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.  Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed! Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. \pend 

\pstart \speakerd{Second.} Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amed \pend
\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. I recommend modifying the previous question (I have already done it) instead of posting a new similar question. This question will be very likely to be closed as an _exact_ duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477875/indent-with-parallel-text-hebrew-yiddish-latin-german) in a short while.

Comment: I'll close this one – thank you